# What does the Anomaly_Score in Pycaret.anomaly library mean?

Tags: unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection, pycaret

If we use the *assign_model()* function from *pycaret.anomaly* library we get a dataframe with two additional columns **Anomaly** and **Anomaly_Score** as output. What does the Anomaly_Score column mean in this dataframe and how is its value calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyCaret uses the PyOd library for anomaly detection. The anomaly score of an input sample is computed based on different detector algorithms. For consistency, outliers are assigned with larger anomaly scores.
Wow it is calculated depends on the algorithm used for anomaly detection.
Check out the documentation: https://pyod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyod.models.html and search for: "anomaly score".